# Configure Jacoco separate multiple reports from multiple exec files in Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

In my spring boot project, I want to run/report unit test and integration test seprately.
The requirements are:

1. Gradle should 2 tasks: one for unit test, one run for integration test.
2. After execting 2 tasks: build/jacoco folder should have: integrationTest.exec, test.exec
3. Jacoco should generate 2 reports, under build/reports should have: jacoco-ut(for unit test) and jacoco-it(for integration test)

I already create 2 tasks for running unit test and integration test

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        exclude '**/*IntegrationTest.class'
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        include '**/*IntegrationTest.class'
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    executionData test, integrationTest
    dependsOn test, integrationTest
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
```

Jacoco generated 2 file exec: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia85o.png)
But under reports folder I only have 1 jacoco folder here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/namBd.png) I expected jacoco-ut, jacoco-it.

How do to re-config this achive 2 folder?